# How to populate a select option or dropdown list value add by 4?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

How to populate a select option value is add by 4 and the label is start at 0.5 in jQuery?

for example;

```
<select>
     <option value="4">0.5</option>
     <option value="8">1.0</option>
     <option value="12">1.5</option>
</select>
```

and will end to

```
<option value="480">60.0</option>
```

I dont want to code it one by one and multiply it by 4 in every value.. I had a hard time searching for an answer. I'm not a javascript programmer. waaaahhh!
Please help me out of this guys!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean mutiply by 4 or add 4 in each value?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan yes sir add 4! :) thanks

Comment: @wong2 I have a basic knowledge in javascript :)

Comment: then I believe that you could figure this out by yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery

```
var select = $('select');
for(var v = 4, t = 0.5; v <= 480; v = v + 4, t = t + 0.5) {
    select.append('<option value="' + v + '">' + t + '</option>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/pCjdX/

As a function:

```
var select = $('select');

populateDropDown($('select'), 4, 480, 4, 0.5, 0.5);

function populateDropDown(select, startValue, endValue, incrementValue, startText, incrementText) {
    for(var v = startValue, t = startText; v <= endValue; v = v + incrementValue, t = t + incrementText) {
        select.append('<option value="' + v + '">' + t + '</option>');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/pCjdX/1/

Comment: is this possible to run in DOM?

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this with [jquery](http://www.jquery.com)

```
    <select id="mylist">
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
       var x = 4;
       var y = 0.5;
     while(x <=480)
{
   $("#mylist").append("<option value='" + x + "'>" + y + "</option>");
   x += 4;
   y +=0.5;
}    

    });
    </script>
```

WITHOUT JQUERY

```
 <select id="mylist">
        </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
        var html = "";
                    var x = 4;
                    var y = 0.5;
                    while (x <= 480) {
                        html += "<option value='" + x + "'>" + y + "</option>";
                        x += 4;
                        y += 0.5;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = html;
        }
     </script>
```

Comment: Is this can be made as a function in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest solutions I can think of in as few lines as possible:

```
$(function() {
  $i = 480;
  while($i > 0) {
    $("#mylist").append('<option value="' + $i + '">' + $i/8 + '</option>');
    $i -= 4;
  }
});
```

Here's a whole HTML5 page to run in your browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jquery for</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="mylist"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $i = 480;
  while($i > 0) {
    $("#mylist").append('<option value="' + $i + '">' + $i/8 + '</option>');
    $i -= 4;
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```